# Java Twitter4j cant find properties file when using multiple Modules in Project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, module, twitter4j

im trying to write a simple Java App with twitter4j and openjfx using intellij.
In Intellij i created a new Empty project and defined a few new Maven Modules inside this project to build a workspace where i can develope more than one application at once. I created a module called "tweetalot" with Maven and the openjfx Archetype to test out twitter4j Library, but the program always fails, because twitter4j doesnt find the twitter4j.properties file.
It only finds the properties file, when i put it in the main project directory "JavafxbuchÜbungen"(where also the .idea folder is in), not even when i put it in the root or ressource folder of the tweetalot module the twitter4j.properties file can be found.

What can i do to place the twitter4j.properties file in a modules folder and not the main Project folder?
Heres my folder Structure:
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3hxU.png)
And here is the whole Project uploadet on github (The main Project Folder was renamed from JavafxbuchÜbungen to JavafxbuchUebungen, because i couldnt use a Ü on github.
[Link for Project on Github](https://github.com/TechnoDummy/JavafxbuchUebungen.git)
Source Code of app is below.

```
package de.javafxbuch;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import twitter4j.*;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Label label = new Label();
        root.getChildren().add(label);
        try{
            Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
            ResponseList<Status> homeTimeline = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
            label.setText(homeTimeline.get(0).getText());
        }
        catch (TwitterException ex){
            //
        }
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.setTitle("Tweetalot");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please add the project structure and point out where modules and property files are placed that the api does not find it ?

Comment: Hey, i did edit my first post with a screenshot of the Folder Structure. The Folder JavafxbuchÜbungen in the explorer is my intellij project folder, the 3 folders below are my addet Modules. As you can see i tried placing the twitter4j.properties in the root folder of my Module tweetalot3, but i also tried a´to put it in tweetalot3-src-main-resources folder. All that doesnt work, it only finds the properties file when i place it in the main Project folder "JavafxbuchÜbungen" which you see opened in the windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how mvn / gradle - convention based build systems expect resources.

Property file `twitter4j.properties` should be present under directory `tweetalot3/src/main/resourrces`. From the screenshot it is not clear whether property file is present in the mentioned directory

Comment: This is what i wrote in my comment below. If i put it to the resource folder (tweetalot3/src/main/resources it will also not get found. It only gets found when i put it to the main Project folder "JavafxbuchÜbungen" where the 3 Modules are located inside.(See the windows explorer)

Comment: How is the application run ? Is the project an intellij project or mvn project ? Is your project open source hosted in public ?

Comment: Its an Empty Intellij Project and i imported the 3 Modules as Maven Modules. I uploadet the project to github under https://github.com/TechnoDummy/JavafxbuchUebungen.git